# Show that $||f||_{1,p}=||\dot{f}||_p$ is a norm on this space

Tags: functional-analysis

For the space $C^{\infty}_0([-1,1])$ of continously differentiable functions on $[-1,1]$ with $f(-1)=f(1)=0$

I would like to show that $||f||1,p=||\dot{f}||_p$ is a norm on this space.

I have noticed that since the norm is defined using the derivative of $f$ and hence i wondered what subtleties may exist when checking the $3$ requirements of norms.

The requirement that $||f||_{1,p}=0 \iff f=0$, is something to mention in the proof, and taken care of by the definition of the space.

However, the other two requirements seem to be straightfoward.

My question is this: Am i missing any details with the $||\dot{f}||_p$ norm that I 2ould need to mention in a proof?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your proof for $\|f\|_{1,p} = 0 \implies f=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Whether showing $\| \cdot \|_{1,p}$ is a norm on $X = \{ f \in C_0^\infty([-1,1]) \mid f(-1) = f(1) = 0\}$ has some details you should mind or not can only be answered in one way:

- Start writing your proof and see if something comes up.

Comment: I indeed have. The scalar condition seemed fine. And the triangle inequality, just seems to be a statement of the minkowski inequality, but with $\dot{f}$ instead of $f$. I just wasn't sure if I was missing something subtle.

Comment: @AltonJones if you don't show us your proof, we can't tell.

Comment: @AltonJones If you give use your proof of the triangle inequality, we can say if there is a subtlety missing or not. But my guess, as I don'want to write it out, is that it is indeed the triangle inequality for $f'$ instead of $g'$ and linearity of the derivative.

Comment: The triangle inequality is literally: by the Minkowski Inequality, $||\dot{f} + \dot{g}|| \le ||\dot{f}|| + ||\dot{g}||$. The fact that we are defining the norm on the derivative, doesn't seem to change this, since derivatives of all orders exist. I'm wondering if I am missing any details...

Comment: @AltonJones Yes, you're missing $\| f + g\| = \| ( f+ g )'\| = \| f'+ g'\|$.

Comment: That's right. Thanks.